# How to code a Node.js Server to support multi-server horizontal scaling

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine

does anyone have experience in using node.js server in a Cloud computing environment like Google Compute Engine/AWS that allows auto-scaling?

Is there any things to watch out for in your code if provider clones your node.js server across servers(Horizontal scaling)?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything particular to NodeJS in this scenario. The general rules for horizontal scaling for any web environment also apply to node applications. This is the first article I found on the subject when I did a search just now: https://blog.openshift.com/best-practices-for-horizontal-application-scaling/ It appears to cover the points you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your Node.js server is stateless, you can create a instance template of your server and use [Google Autoscalar](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) to automatically add or remove instances from a managed instance group based on increases or decreases in load. I recommend watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfbEwfYjKl4).